# Entire script for Google Analytics for tracking custom dimensions on JS

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I was having issues for traking custom dimensions with our GA. I have found several pieces of sample code in official documentation and some blogs. All of them are different of each ther.

By the end, i'd implemented the fallowing piece of code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1',{custom_map:{'dimension1':'semana'}});

  gtag('send', 'pageview', { 'semana':'semana 11' }); // first attempt 

  gtag('event', 'pageview', { 'semana':'semana 12' }); // second attempt 

  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'semana 3'); // third attempt. ERROR: ga is not defined

</script>
```

(where xxxxxx ir our Id.)

I also create a custom dimension in the GA account. however I cant see track the custom dimension created. I suspect that those events are not sent to the GA.

Am I doing something wrong? Im not able to see our custom dimensions tracked by the GA, as seen below (yeelow mark is the custom dimension)

[image]

In this case, what are the full Javascript code that allows me to track a properly a custom dimension in our website?

Comment: ga() is analytics.sj gtag is gtag.js  You are mixing diffrent versions of Google Analytics.  try following this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: @DaImTo this is exactly what i've been trying on the first and second attempt. I copied the code from that link, and changed the UID and the custom domain name

Comment: Did you setup the custom dimension in the UI prior to sending the data to it?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works 
for me was.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'semana 3');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Exactly... while in your first example you mix 2 types of tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the custom dimension on Analytics has id '1'?

Your first example generates an error because the code is of gtag() and you call ga() that does not exist, but the second code should work properly.

Comment: im pretty sure.